# No me envía el valor de un vector en C

Tags: c, punteros

tengo un error en mi código y no puedo descubrir cual es: necesito saber cual es el menor valor de un vector (usando punteros) pero en lugar de recibir el contenido para poder compararlo estoy recibiendo una posición de memoria:

```
main()
{
    int ventasSemanales[semanas];
    int menor = 0;
    semanaMenorVent(ventasSemanales, &menor);
    printf("la semana de menores ventas fue la numero: %d\n", menor+1);
}
void semanaMenorVent(int ventasSemanales[semanas], int *semanaMenor){
    int numeroMenor= ventasSemanales[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < semanas; i++)
    {
        if (ventasSemanales[i] < numeroMenor)
        {
            numeroMenor = ventasSemanales[i];
            *semanaMenor = i;
        }
        printf("%d\n", *semanaMenor);
    }
}
```

Gracias por la colaboracion

Comment: si alguna respuesta soluciono tu problema puedes marcarla como solución, si encontraste una solución revisa [answer] para redactar correctamente una solución.

Answer (score 2):

Cambié algunas cosas, la función la puse arriba del `main`, que debe devolver un entero de valor `0` para verificar que se ejecutó correctamente, hice que devuelva un **entero** (`int`) en vez un `void`, y el segundo argumento fue cambiado, en vez del valor a cambiar, es la longitud del array. Ahora detecta la longitud del array con `sizeof`, pero fuera de la función, ya que dentro no se puede.

Hacer esto, `int ventasSemanales[semanas]` está mal, no es la manera de recibir el argumento `semanas`, y además no es necesario, ya es posible conocer la longitud de tal array.

Código final:

```
int semanaMenorVent(int ventasSemanales[],int longitud)
{
    int semanaMenor = -1;
    int numeroMenor = ventasSemanales[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<longitud; i++)
    {
        if (ventasSemanales[i] < numeroMenor)
        {
            numeroMenor = ventasSemanales[i];
            semanaMenor = i;
        }
        printf("%i\n", semanaMenor);
    }
    return semanaMenor;
}
int main()
{
    int ventasSemanales[]={9,5,6,9,2,4,3,9,3,3};
    int longitud=sizeof(ventasSemanales)/sizeof(ventasSemanales[0]);
    int menor = semanaMenorVent(ventasSemanales,longitud);
    printf("Longitud: %i\n",longitud);
    printf("la semana de menores ventas fue la numero: %d\n", menor+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, el sizeof no te devuelve el tamaño del array. En el ejemplo que has puesto el array tiene tamaño siete, pero si pones un `printf("longitudArray=%d\n",longitudArray)` dentro de tu función `semanaMenorVent` veras que no te imprime siete. Pero tu respuesta está bastate bien, solo añade el segundo parámetro a la función con el tamaño del array, pásale un 7 y ya lo tienes correcto. Y tienes que iterar en el bucle hasta `i<longitudArray` no hasta `i<longitudArray-1`.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Acabo de inventar un truco para obtener la longitud de un array, que el último valor termine con un número mágico. Decime qué te parece.

Comment: Lo que has hecho funciona y funciona bien. Pero tiene el problema de que no puedes emplear el número 0 en el array. Si de todas formas le tienes que pasar un entero a la función mejor pasarle la longitud. Para que no te toque ajustar el código cada vez que cambias la longitud del array puedes usar `sizeof(ventasSemanales)/sizeof(ventasSemanales[0])` para saber la longitud del array (usa esto como parámetro de longitud al llamar a `semanaMenorVent`). Pero ten en cuenta que eso solo funciona en el main. Dentro de la función no sabemos el tamaño de array si no se lo pasamos.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Listo.

Comment: Así el código está bien. Ahora que el código lo tienes bien sería necesario editar la explicación en castellano que diste pues ya no se corresponde con el código que tienes.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Sí, no me había dado cuenta, ahora creo que está bien.